# When I am trying to scan the Java application in HP Fortify SCA Scan Wizard I seen an Error Unresolved Classes

Tags: java, jar, owasp, fortify, fortify-source

SCA Wizard has noticed the following jars contain packages which are the same as the source:
C:\Users\12345\Desktop\Work\xyz\xyz\xyz\Lib\sslorb\ebtibo.jar

It would be advisable to add the source for these jars into the Scan, this would allow for a more complete set of results

**How to get rid of this error? Any Suggestions would be appreciable**

Comment: Might need more detail to be able to answer this completely. Can you show the command you run (via the wizard)? In general, if Fortify has the source .java files in addition to the .class files (including those in Jar files), then it can better match up findings with specific code to help you analyze the results.

Comment: 1. Opened Scan wizard from all program files.

Comment: # Opened Scan wizard from all program files -> Add Project Root-> click Next->  Now I seen the error as Unresolved classes->chosen Next-> chosen the Java source Version 1.8->   SQL Type PL/SQL-> Translation and Scan-> chosen Next  -> Now a Fortify.bat file was created so i just double clicked on it,  where the command prompt started

Comment: [error]: Unexpected exception while resolving file PersonMapper.java
[error]: Unexpected exception while resolving file UserMapper.java
[warning]: Could not locate the root (WEB-INF) of the web application. Please bu
ild your web application and try again.
[error]: Unexpected exception while resolving file newsstory.jsp
[warning]: The following references to java classes could not be resolved. Pleas
e make sure to supply all the required jar files that contain these classes to S
CA.

Comment: [warning]: The Java frontend was unable to resolve the following include:
        /base/formatting.html at C:\Users\ at C:\Users\firmsearch.jsp:74.
[warning]: Unexpected exception while parsing file (javascript) C:/Users/_vti_cnf/clsAccountInfo
.js: Parse error at line 2, column 28.  Encountered: May
[warning]: Unexpected exception while parsing file (javascript) C:/Users
/AppData/Local/Fortify/sca6.3/build/EEE/extracted/javascript/C/Users/canconversion01.html.js: null
[warning]: Unexpected exception while parsing file (javascript) C:/Users/planning.js: Parse error at line 51,
column 23